# how to search with filter (file extension) in 'NavigateTo' in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio 2013, I know we can do Quick Search by using Keyword **CTRL + ,** is there any way we can filter with the file extension.

let's suppose I have a different type of files which is starting from 'dummyfiles' i want to search all dummyfiles where file extension is .cshtml

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible with quick search but it is possible in general. Open the Find and Replace window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) and open the "Find options" dialog and then put your target file extension in the "Look at these file types:" field.